# WPF Grid how to sign on RowDefinitions changed?

Tags: wpf, grid, wpf-controls

Is it possible to catch event on RowCollection changed?

```
new Grid().RowDefinitions.Changed+=???
```

Comment: Hmm... I think an easier way would be to use an ItemsControl and add your "Grid Row Items" to an ObservableCollection and bind this collection to the ItemsSource property on the ItemsControl. You can now leverage CollectionChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is not a best way to perform this but I using this solution:

```
private count=0;
void OnLayoutUpdated(...)
{
  if(count!=Grid().RowDefinitions.Count)
  {
     // Do what you need.
  }
}
```

Also we can sign each RowDefinition on value changed if we need to know that value was changed.